# How to show current date and time on the navigation bar using oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

As the question states, I want to show the current date and time on every page of my Application. Is it possible to show it on the Navigation bar list? Also, I would like to avoid making a display item for every page to show the date and time.
[Red Box shows where I want to place it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91SQS.jpg)

Comment: In my opinion, that's a futile job. Today's *computers* display that info anyway (e.g. in bottom right corner of my MS Windows operating system) so - what benefit do you expect (apart from doing it as an exercise)? Also, what do you call "current time"? If seconds are to be displayed, should they be *ticking*? If you'd display a "static" value, there's no much use of it. You enter a page and stay there for 10 minutes - time that was valid at the beginning isn't valid "now". As I said: a quick look in the *bottom right* direction solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could place it in the navigation bar list entry as a link that goes nowhere, such as URL `javascript:void(0)`

The source could be from an application item, perhaps called F_TIME_LABEL, that you compute on each page open, then substituted into the link using this as the label:

```
&F_TIME_LABEL.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

Step 1: Create an application item called say, DATETIME, from Shared Components > Application Items.

Step 2: Create an application computation from Shared Components > Application Computations. Choose computation item as DATETIME, set computation type to SQL query and computation to

select to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')  from dual;
(use whichever format you wish to display).

Step 3: Create a Navigation Bar entry with list entry label &DATETIME. with no target.

Log out and log in to the application and you should see the date displayed on the navigation bar.

[image: Date time in navigation bar]